# can I launch my website relying on the beta of the google javascript client library?

Tags: google-authentication

I want to use oauth 2.0 to authenticate users on my site and I would prefer javascript to do it. But the javascript library is a beta so can I rely on it ? my only concern is that google may stop(shut down) api access for a while after they are done with the beta testing and before they launch the actual thing. In such a case, my site would become unaccessible for that period of time. I don't want that to happen.

so can I use javascript library or should I use other libraries which are not beta ?